# Only a specifc part of mesh being shown in OBJECT mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have no idea how I stumbled upon this problem. But a huge part of my mesh seems to be missing in Object and Wireframe mode for some reason. The rendered and material view are perfectly fine somehow. I'm using blender 3.0.1.

This is the wireframe mode
[image: Wireframe mode]

The object mode
[image: The object mode]

The material view, which is, somehow, unaffected
[image: Material View]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The highlighted area in the viewport indicates that you have accidentally created a *Clipping Region* by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and then dragging a rectangle with your mouse.

To clear this view region, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> again.

Comment: The other clue is the notification in the upper-left corner of the images which says "User Perspective (Clipped)"! :^)

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon and John, that fixed it!

Comment: @JohnEason Yes, of course you're right. I just mentioned the highlighted area in the viewport because it will also show in _Solid_ view when _Overlays_ are disabled (so that the text will not be visible).